# RSS web part error "Please verify the settings and url for this feed."

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, rss

I have a RSS web part in SharePoint 2016 that suddenly not displaying the feed correctly.

[image: RSS error]

The error I found in the ULS log is "The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

[image: SSL error ULS]

I have already added the SSL cert, the intermediate and root cert of the news site to the SharePoint trust and server trust folder.

I have verified that it's a legit URL feed that works on SharePoint Online, but not on this SP2016.

Please advise on what else I need to do.

Comment: Is this RSS feed originating outside your domain?

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz it is in the same domain actually

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using in your farm?  NTLM or claims?

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz we're using Claims based auth

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, check the permissions of the account that is reading the RSS source.  If the permissions have changed, you have an [AuthZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) issue.

If the account reading the source has the requisite permissions to read the data source, you are dealing with an [AuthN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) issue, likely caused by a changed or expired password.